# bloquear un jframe al abrir otro jframe

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe

Tengo una aplicacion que abre un jframe y necesito que cuando se abra el mismo me bloquee la aplicacion por detras, que no me deje tocar la aplicacion de tras, que el focus de la aplicacion este en nuevo jframe. Que metodo de jframe me permite esto?

Comment: No es posible hacer eso con un `JFrame`, ¿por qué no utilizas un `JDialog`? La clase `JDialog` utiliza [modalidad](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html) lo cual te permite hacer lo que deseas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que sería usando this.setVisible(false); o si querés que esté visible pero no responda, poner para cada componente ej:boton1.setEnabled(false);

Answer (score 0):

Para el 99% de los casos lo mejor será usar un dialogo.
Si por alguna razón debes de hacerlo de todas formas con JFrames esta es la manera:

- indicar que el foco no debe poder pasar al frame principal

  ```
  setFocusableWindowState(false);
  ```
- deshabilitar el frame

  ```
  setEnabled(false);
  ```
- en caso de que tengas componentes debes deshabilitarlos uno por uno para dar un mejor aspecto visual

### Frame principal

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class JMarco1 extends JFrame {
    
    private JMarco2 marco2 = new JMarco2();

    /**
     * Creates new form JMarco1
     */
    public JMarco1() {
        initComponents();
        marco2.setMarco1(this);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new JLabel();
        jButton1 = new JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        jLabel1.setText("Hola soy el marco 1");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1);

        jButton1.setText("Abrir Marco2");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().add(jButton1);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        marco2.setVisible(true);
        setFocusableWindowState(false);
        setEnabled(false);
        jButton1.setEnabled(false);
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JMarco1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new JMarco1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    
    public void enableButton(){
        jButton1.setEnabled(true);
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private JButton jButton1;
    private JLabel jLabel1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

### Frame secundario

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class JMarco2 extends JFrame {

    private JMarco1 marco1;

    /**
     * Creates new form JMarco2
     */
    public JMarco2() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        jLabel1.setText("Hola soy el marco 2");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        jLabel2.setText("intenta ir al frame anterior y veras que  no puedes hasta cerrar este");
        getContentPane().add(jLabel2, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public void setMarco1(JMarco1 marco1) {
        this.marco1 = marco1;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        marco1.setFocusableWindowState(true);
        marco1.setEnabled(true);
        marco1.enableButton();
        super.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean b) {
        super.setVisible(b);
    }
    
    


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private JLabel jLabel1;
    private JLabel jLabel2;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```